# Toggle button click not responding in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two buttons in angularjs to activate and deactivate user my problem is I want to make one button when I click the button change her color and text I try to change but no success.

Someone correct me my Attempt

This is my two button :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Active" ng-click="Active(User)" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Desactive" ng-click="Desactive(User)" />
```

I try to change them but I don't know what the problem :

```
<div ng-class="User.IsActive? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-danger' " 
     ng-click="User.IsActive?Active(User):Desactive(User)">
         {{ User.IsActive ? 'Active' : 'Desactive'}}
</div>
```